# C++ why templating a class resolves undefined class error

Tags: c++, templates, nested

I encounter a compiler error when I try to declare a nested class with a member of the outer class type:

```
class A {
public:
    class Anested {
        A a; // Error: 'A::Anested::a' uses undefined class 'A'
    };
};
```

Changing the outer class to a class template removes the compiler error:

```
template <size_t n>
class B {
public:
    class Bnested {
        B b; // Fine
    };
};

int main() {
    B<0> b; // Fine
    B<0>::Bnested bn; // Fine
}
```

Why should one declaration be allowed but not the other, especially since in the example above the template argument is entirely arbitrary? I'm compiling using MSVC with C++14 language standard, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of `A::Anested`, `A` is an incomplete type when `a` is declared, the compiler hasn't seen the whole declaration of `A` yet, so it can't declare `a` as an instance of `A`.  Incomplete types only work when dealing with references and pointers.

In the case of `B::Bnested`, templates are handled in multiple stages. The compiler knows that `B<n>` exists when `b` is declared, but it does not know the actual value of `n` yet, so it does not instantiate `b` yet. When later code instantiates an instance of `B<n>` with an actual argument for `n`, the compiler will then know the complete type of `B<n>`, and can instantiate `b` with that same type.

Comment: I think the important thing to realize about templates is that they don't create a class.  Rather they define a *recipe* for creating a class once the template type is known, so the actual concrete class gets defined later.

Comment: B is a result of th intenal compiler working. I do not think that this behavior is defined in the standard. Does it?